# The shape of the array is changing once I save the numpy array to csv file and reading it back

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, export-to-csv, import-from-csv

I have a small piece of code that should write a 2D numpy array to a csv which I guess is doing it right. Once I write it to csv, I'm trying to read it as a numpy array and print the shape of the array which is not the same shape as the array what I wrote.
Please find the code:

```
print(op_arr.shape)
np.savetxt('Train.csv', op_arr, fmt="%10.2f")
a=np.genfromtxt('Train.csv',delimiter=',')
print(a.shape)
```

The output is :

> (10, 30001)
>
> (10,)

Can someone help me understand and fix the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't store your file with `delimiter=","`. So why do you read it with this keyword? Remove it and your array should be as expected.

Comment: Thanks I missed to add the delimiter while saving which caused the issue thanks..! @MrT